# I copied CS Dojo's code but mine doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to learning Python and I've been watching CS Dojo's tutorials for absolute beginners.
There's a video about solving sample problems from CodingBat with this particular problem, "String-2 double_char" [text](https://codingbat.com/prob/p170842)

I simply copied CS Dojo's solution in the video but mine doesn't seem to work.

Here's the problem from CodingBat: **String-2 double_char**

Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

For example,

```
`double_char('The') → 'TThhee'

double_char('AAbb') → 'AAAAbbbb'

double_char('Hi-There') → 'HHii--TThheerree'`
```

Here's the code:

```
`def double_char(str):
    to_return = ""
    for i in (str):
     to_return += i * 2
     return to_return`
```

when I run the code, it just returns the first character of str.

For example,
`double_char("hello")` only returns 'hh' instead of 'hheelloo'

Answer (score 2):

You're returning from your function after only one iteration of str
Note: Untested code

Try changing this

```
def double_char(str):
    to_return = ""
    for i in (str):
     to_return += i * 2
     return to_return
```

to

```
def double_char(str):
    to_return = ""
    for i in (str):
     to_return += i * 2
    return to_return
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the slight difference between both codes is the indentation of the return. In the second snippet, return has less indentation which means it returns only after all the iteration is done.

Comment: @EskayAmadeus, you're correct Guess I thought the different indention was obvious.

Comment: Thanks for this! I overlooked the indentation. It worked after I fixed it.

Comment: @ZerachielViolet I realize you can’t upvote an answer, but it is customary on StackOverflow to “accept” an answer when it provides a solution. Glad it worked for you.